# Excel save as .xlsx from .xlsm file extension

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am trying to write a VBScript to open an excel.
Run the macro and Save it as xlsx. Post this close the excel document.

Pardon my knowledge of VBScript as I am still novice and lack detailed knowledge of VBScript.

However, this is important and the piece of code I have written is not able to help me out.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Report0165.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Test value"

objExcel.Application.Run "Report0165.xlsm"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Report0165.xlsx", FileFormat = 51
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close saveChanges=True

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

I am trying and still I am unable to do this basic things: I need to execute all the macros inside the excel. Hence I have not specified the macro name.

> a. Open excel with macro
>
> b. run macro
>
> c. Save the xlsm to xlsx
>
> d. close the document

Can  anyone please guide on where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This code should get you there other than in my test it opened up the `xlsm` with macros disabled.

- Pls note I have changed the path
- You don;t need to make Excel visible when automating
- Turning off alerts stops the prompt when you overwrite `Report0165.xlsx`
- `FileFormat` can't be used in a vbs
- your code wasn't specifying a macro to be run inside `Report0165`

*updated as apparently OP didn't want the new book that question adds with `objExcel.Workbooks.Add`*

```
*code*


    Set objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\Report0165.xlsm")

    'Objexcel.Application.Visible = True
    Objexcel.DisplayAlerts = false
    objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Test value"

    'objExcel.Run "Report0165.xlsm!Test"
    objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\temp\Report0165.xlsx", 51
    objWorkbook.Close

    Objexcel.DisplayAlerts = true

    objexcel.Application.Quit
    WScript.Echo "Finished."
    WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Thanks..However I cannot specify the macro name. I want all the macros present inside the excel to run.

Comment: The code is not working. It is just writing a new file with "Test Value" content inside it.. I want the same xlsm to be saved as xlsx.

Comment: The code is repeating the same steps your question did which added a new workbook. I will update my answer, but your question isn't as you intended it.

Comment: Ok.. I got the code from some link and I was trying to execute the same. Pardon my knowledge of VB as I am not aware of much of the stuff. What I essentially want is open the excel, run the macro, save that excel as xlsx..The code snippet pasted by me might not be correct as I am still figuring out how to just carry out these basic steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AngelsandDemons no probs. How does the revised code go (other than running code?)